# Как сделать данный header-line(Текст справа, картинка слева)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

очень нужна помощь в реализации header-line, сделал пока так, но понимаю что не правильно, и грызет душу данная штуковина.
Надеюсь на Вашу помощь, спасибо!

[image: Данный header-line]

```css
.top-line {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.top-line a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 120px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.top-line .top-text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.top-line .top-text p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: url(../img/icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.top-line .top-text p:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-position: 0 -15px;
}

.top-line .top-text p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-position: 0 -85px;
}

.top-line .top-text p span {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-line">
  <a href=""><img src="img/logo-top.png" alt="Logo"></a>
  <div class="top-text">
    <p><span>100%</span> натурально</p>
    <p><span>100%</span> эффективно</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что именно вас смущает? Вполне жизнеспособный вариант, единственное я бы `p` заменил на `div` и убрал `.top-line` из селекторов для уменьшения специфичности. Все остальное может быть вкусовщиной.

Comment: Не знаю, как-то не семантично смотрится=)

Comment: вместо <div class="top-line"> напишите <header class="top-line">. Так будет семантичнее.